# Nice menus error when implement in zen themes

Tags: 7, navigation, theming

I copied the following code:

```
<div id="navigation">

  <?php if (module_exists('nice_menus')): ?>
  <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">
    <?php
      print theme('nice_menus_main_menu', array(
        'direction' => 'down',
        'depth' => -1,
      )); ?>

  </nav>
<?php elseif ($main_menu): ?>
  <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">
    <?php
    print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
      'links' => $main_menu,
      'attributes' => array(
        'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
      ),
      'heading' => array(
        'text' => t('Main menu'),
        'level' => 'h2',
        'class' => array('element-invisible'),
      ),
    )); ?>
  </nav>
```

and replaced the default code in page.tpl.php (zen theme),

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
    <nav id="main-menu" role="navigation">
      <?php
      print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
        'links' => $main_menu,
        'attributes' => array(
          'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
        ),
        'heading' => array(
          'text' => t('Main menu'),
          'level' => 'h2',
          'class' => array('element-invisible'),
        ),
      )); ?>
    </nav>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

The sub-menu is able to drop down but the main menu can't be horizontal; meaning the main menu can't be "inline", because the system didn't run the `elseif` look I think. So I want to know what the problem is? And what should I do to re-correct the zen theme coding?

Comment: what i need is just want let the main menu display in horizontal view not vertical, hope someone can help me